# Will creating new php.ini overwrites original file

Tags: .htaccess, php

I have a **linux** server. I am unable to upload images to it form my application. I checked **phpinfo()** in that i found **upload_tmp_dir** is assigned a **no value**. I feel this is the reason for  the issue.

I tried editing **.htaccess** but some say it is not always a good method. So i tried searching for **php.ini** file on my server. Surprisingly i dint find it.

So, If i create a new php.ini file in root folder, will this effect my server?

I am just worrying if at all the php.ini overwrites i will definitely run into big problems

So can i proceed adding only this code in my new php.ini file ?

```
; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
;upload_tmp_dir = www/temp/uploads/
```

**UPDATE:**

It throws these warnings

```
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(xml/xm.jpg.asp) [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/appsimon/public_html/api/update_xml.php on line 31
     PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file() [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpLP5q96' to 'xml/xm.jpg.asp' in /home/appsimon/public_html/api/update_xml.php on line 31
     PHP Warning:  fopen(xml/xm.jpg.asp) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/appsimon/public_html/api/update_xml.php on line 33
     PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(xml/xm.jpg.asp) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/appsimon/public_html/api/update_xml.php on line 35
```

Comment: [From the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) *"If not specified PHP will use the system's default"*. I don't think you need to worry about it. Also `phpinfo()` will show you which configuration file it's using

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with **.htaccess** file. .htaccess is basically processed by Apache but **php.ini** used by PHP compiler which is in fact an Apache module.

If you do not have **php.ini**, maybe something went wrong with your PHP installation. Just grab a default **php.ini** and put it beside **php.exe**.

You can also overwrite the functionality you want in the **php.ini** that you place in your root directory of web server not the root directory of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it overrides the **php.ini** on the server. You can only specify some of the values in your new **php.ini**. Only the specified values get over-ridden.

You can also use **PHP** for overriding some of the **php.ini** values (only if your hosting provider allows this.)